# How can I expose a dynamic jQuery triggered event from inside a custom jQuery script to the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to expose an event when a page change is fired, and ideally a function to change the `settings.pageCount` .

The following script is a custom jQuery extension which adds paging to a table, and it works very well. The problem is that from the usage side of things, I would like to elevate control to the user of this script to be able to listen for when the `repaginate` event has been fired, and when it has been completed.

I would also like to offer a method so that at runtime (say from a drop-down box the developer decided to use), they can set the value for `settings.pageCount` (this is the maximum number of rows to be shown at a  time) without having them call `$('table').tables( { options ... } );` again.

```js
(function ( $ ) {
 $.fn.tables = function( options ) {
  
  var settings = $.extend({
   page: 0,
   pageCount: 10,
  }, options );
  
  $thead = this.find('thead');
  $tbody = this.find('tbody');
  $tfoot = this.find('tfoot > tr > td').attr('colspan', $tbody.find('tr')[0].cells.length);
  
  var numRows = $tbody.find('tr').length;
  var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / settings.pageCount);

  this.bind('repaginate', function() {
   $tbody.find('tr').removeClass('visible').slice(settings.page * settings.pageCount, (settings.page + 1) * settings.pageCount).addClass('visible');
  });
  this.trigger('repaginate');

  $tfoot.find('td').html('');
  for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
   $('<a></a>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
    newPage: page
   }, function(event) {
    settings.page = event.data['newPage'];
    $(this).trigger('repaginate');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   }).appendTo($tfoot).addClass('clickable');
  }
  
  $tfoot.find('a:first-child').addClass('active');
  
  return this;
 };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
:root {
  --tables-even-color: #CDEDF7;
  --tables-odd-color: #90C3D4;
}

.tables {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Header */
.tables thead  > tr {
 background: #3E8096;
 color: #CDEDF7;
}

.tables thead > tr > td {
 padding: 4px;
}
.tables thead > tr > td:hover{
 background: #CDEDF7 !important;
}

/* Footer */
.tables tfoot  > tr {
 background: #3E8096;
 color: #CDEDF7;
}

.tables tfoot > tr > td > a {
 border: 1px solid #3E8096;
 padding: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
}

.tables tfoot > tr > td > a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #CDEDF7;
}

.tables tfoot > tr > td > a.active {
 background: #CDEDF7;
 color: #3E8096;
}

/* Rows */
.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
 background: #CDEDF7;
 color: #90C3D4;
}
.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(even):hover {
 background: #18EAF5;
 color: #90C3D4;
}

.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #90C3D4;
 color: #CDEDF7;
}
.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
 background: #18EAF5;
 color: #90C3D4;
}

.tables tbody > tr {
 display: none;
}

.tables tbody > tr.visible {
 display: table-row !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tables').tables();

                // Handle some events ??
              
       $('button').click(function() {
                      // SET:  settings.pageCount = 20;
                });
   })
  </script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <button>Show 20 rows per page</button>
 
  <table class="tables">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Column 1</td>
     <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>aa</td>
     <td>ab</td>
    </tr>
 
    <tr>
     <td>ac</td>
     <td>ad</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
   </tbody>
   
   <tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="1"></td></tr>
   </tfoot>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

jQuery documentation shows that I can build my extension in a way that the user can do something like the following :

```
$('selector').Foo(function() { });
```

or

```
$('selector').Foo(
   barEvent: function() {

   }
);
```

I have also seen cases, where to change the settings for a extension, one could just call :

```
$('selector').settings.foo = 123;   // or something similar
```

The problem is I don't know how to implement this using my code without breaking it.  I have read through many 'examples' however they all seem to be partial implementations or really outdated (eg, using `init` or `base`)

Comment: You can use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) to fire any event

Comment: possible i am missing something in that statement, however I do make use of `trigger()` inside the function.  That part of the problem is that is not accessible from inside the html portion  (user side) to call a trigger on.  I will expand a bit more since something is being lost in translation here.